# Not sure what ruby data structure that is returning from api

Tags: ruby

Here is what I have in my controller

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController

  def index
    require 'open-uri'
    @shakelines = JSON.parse(open("http://api.placemeter.net/api/shake/line/?start=-120&end=0").read())
  end 
end
```

I am not sure what @shakelines contain. What data structure that it is in? array or hash and how to use it.

in my corresponding view

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="medium-12 columns"></div>
          <% @shakelines.each do |shakeline| %>
            <ul>
              <li><%= shakeline %></li>
            </ul>
          <% end %>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I am getting this in my output

```
["average_line_wait_secs", [0, 0, 0]]

["end", 1396627145]

["timestamps", [1396627020, 1396627080, 1396627140]]

["average_line_length", [0, 0, 0]]

["start", 1396627020]
```

it looks like an array? but when I open the url it looks like a hash but its a json object though.

if its an array how do I access the data structure? only using index?
and same with hashes.

also besides doing `<% @shakelines.each do |shakeline| %>` what is just `<% @shakelines %>`? its throwing an error

Comment: Why don't you ask it for its `class`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@shakelines` is a hash. But you're seeing arrays because iterating a hash using [`Hash#each`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Hash.html#method-i-each) yields arrays of key, values pairs.

```
require 'json'
response = '{"average_line_wait_secs": [0, 0, 0], "end": 1396627625, "timestamps": [1396627500, 1396627560, 1396627620], "average_line_length": [0, 0, 0], "start": 1396627500}'
shakelines = JSON.parse(response)
shakelines.class
# => Hash
shakelines.each.to_a
# => [["average_line_wait_secs", [0, 0, 0]],
#     ["end", 1396627625],
#     ["timestamps", [1396627500, 1396627560, 1396627620]],
#     ["average_line_length", [0, 0, 0]],
#     ["start", 1396627500]]
```

Comment: I tried it in irb, and its returning a class of Hash but why do you do `to_a`? for `shakelines.each.to_a`

Comment: @Jngai1297, to demonstrate that `each` yields key-value pairs.

Comment: @Jngai1297, If you mind `.to_a`, try `shakelines.each { |x| p x }`.

Answer (score 1):

What you are receiving is a JSON object, which, in ruby is represented as a hash containing more hashes or arrays.
To access parts of your hash and array, you should use square braces (`[]`):

```
 @shakelines['average_line_wait_secs']
 #=> [0, 0, 0]
 @shakelines['timestamps'][0]
 #=> 1396627500
```

If you want to iterate over the hash, your can use [`#each_pair`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Hash.html#method-i-each_pair)

```
@shakelines.each_pair do |key, value|
  puts key
  puts value.to_s
end
#=> average_line_wait_secs
#=> [0, 0, 0]
#=> end
#=> 1396627625
#=> timestamps
#=> [1396627500, 1396627560, 1396627620]
#=> average_line_length
#=> [0, 0, 0]
#=> start
#=> 1396627500
```